# Get data from first collection and check if exist on second

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Have problem:

userMoments:

```
userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
momentId : {
    type : String,
    required : true
},
pay : {
    type : Number
},
momentActive : {
    type : Boolean,
    default : false
}
```

and moments :

```
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
img : {
    type : String
}
```

I need get all moments from `moments` collection that not isset in collection `userMoments` with some userId

Comment: How much data do you have? How fast do you need the result?

Comment: `momentId` in the `userMoments` collection reference to the `name` in the `moments` collection?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that I would propose the following example:

---

### Algorithm

(1) Get all `momentId` that are stored into `userMoments` in relation with some `userId`

(2) Get all `moments` that are unrelated with `momentId` we got

---

### Code

```
       // Get all momentId
       UserMoments.find({
              $in: arrayThatContainsUserIds,
           }, 'momentId')
           // Make every momentId unique
           .distinct('momentId')
           .exec()
           // get all moments that do not refer to ids we got before
           .then((ret) => find({
              $nin: Array.from(ret, x => x.momentId),
           }))
           .then((ret) => {
              // Here you have your moments
           })
           .catch(err => {});
```

---

### Documentations

[$nin mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

[distinct mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct)

[Array.from documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dn858230(v=vs.94).aspx)

[Promise documentation X.then(...).catch(...)](http://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/)